# Objective C NSMutableArray removeAllObjects will also remove all strings from a file it is loaded from?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` which is loaded from a txt file. There are 5 strings in the file. If I  call `removeAllObjects` will it remove all strings in the file?

I suspect it does not, so how to remove all strings in the file?

Comment: If you don't understand this concept, you shouldn't be working with Objective-C.  Start with Java, until you understand files and such.

Comment: @daniel It is unfair. I want to learn as much as possible, but unfortunately I have almost no free time. That is why I come here and ask.

Comment: Language really doesn't make a difference -- one can learn about file I/O in any language. Objective-C, specifically the MacOS and iOS SDKs, include many (most) of the same high level file manipulation abstractions that the JDK does. For more details, one might start reading here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide

Comment: The problem is that Objective-C is a very awkward language to learn, and you'll learn a lot of bad habits and not pick up on several fundamental concepts.  You must crawl before you can walk, and starting with Objective-C is like climbing out of your crib and enrolling in a marathon race.  If you have limited free time it's important that you invest it wisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file will remain untouched by anything you do to the `NSMutableArray` instance you derive from it.

As to the how to remove the string, it depends on whether you want to remove just a portion of the file or delete the file.  In the case of the latter, the `NSFileManager` method:

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL error:(NSError **)error
```

will do what you want.

On the other hand, if you need more precise control of the file contents, you may need to drop down to C for that, `fopen`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out C functions like fopen. Isn`t `NSFileManager` only Available in Mac OS X v10.6 and later?

Comment: Sorry I mean to ask if this will works for iOS at runtime as well?

Comment: NSFileManager is available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, you'd write something to the file (or simply erase it).